# PHP if/switch concatenated by *

Tags: php, if-statement, concatenation

I was wondering if anybody knew if there was a way to concatenate a * (all) to a string inside an if (or switch) statement. For example if you had a URL called /hello/there and /hello/whats-up ... is there anyway you could have something like the following:

```
if ($url="/hello/" . *) {
sayHello();
} else { sayGoodebye(); }
```

etc... I don't think that's the correct syntax, but if anybody knows what I'm talking about it would be a great help.

Thanks (:

Answer (score 3):

```
$match = "/hello/";
if (substr($url, 0, strlen($match)) === $match) {
   sayHello();
} else {
   sayGoodbye();
}
```

Do not use regular expressions if you don't have to...

Answer (score 0):

You can also check for the position of $match in the $url string:

```
$match = "/hello/";

if (strpos($url, $match) === 0) {
   sayHello();
} else {
   sayGoodbye();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use regular expressions:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html

So it would be something like this:

```
if (ereg("/hello/", $url)) {
sayHello();
} else { sayGoodebye(); }
```

Although that would match anything with "/hello/" in it anywhere, so if you only wanted to match strings that start with "/hello/" you'd have to modify the expression.  The point is, if you've never used regular expressions it's a good thing to invest some time into.  It'll pay off eventually because at some point you're going to need this skill.

Edit: I'll leave my original code here as reference, but please see phihag's comments and use preg_match and the preg_match compatible expression instead of ereg and the expression I used.

Comment: so if I added a ^ before and ? at the end that would match: /hello/* - correct?

Comment: @Yohna P `ereg` is deperecated and should not be used anymore. You should be using `preg_match`.

Comment: @Dara Ó Cairbre Yes, the code would be `if (preg_match('#^/hello/#')) ...`. You could also use the equivalent pattern `^/hello/.*$`.

Comment: phihag, thanks for the notes.  I've edited my original post to point to your contribution.